# In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

This is my code in Matlab: How could I get all values of all 5 images saved? This code only returns the last image! I tried using IM(l) but it gives me an error: `In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.`

```
Amount_measurements = 5;

IM=zeros(2097152,1);
l=1;
for l=(1:Amount_measurements)
    if l < 9
        %index = double(0)+double(0)+double(l+1);
        index = strcat(num2str(double(0)),num2str(double(0)),num2str(double(l+1)));
    elseif l < 99
        index = double(0)+double(l+1);
    else
        index = double(l+1);
    end

    file_name1='trial.nii.gz';
    %disp(file_name1);
    jesu=load_nii(file_name1);

    [x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:256,1:256,1:256);
    [lx,ly,lz] = meshgrid(1:2:256,1:2:256,1:2:256);
    newImage = interp3(x,y,z,jesu.img,lx,ly,lz);
    IM= newImage(:);   
end
```

I want the values newImage(:) to be stored as `IM1=newImage(:) IM2=newImage(:) IM3=newImage(:) IM4=newImage(:)` so on... How could I go about with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned wanting a variable-length version of `IM1=newImage(:) IM2=newImage(:) IM3=newImage(:) IM4=newImage(:)`, you're looking for a cell array.  Try

```
IM{l} = newImage;
```

instead of

```
IM(l) = newImage(:);
```

The important difference is the use of braces rather than parentheses.  Use a right-hand side of`newImage(:)` if you want to reshape into a vector, just `newImage` if you want to preserve it as a matrix.

Comment: Really naive question here. Using braces as you've done, Matlab will automatically create IM1, IM2 etc.? How does it know you want 4 arrays? I guess the rhs must have 4 columns..which makes sense we have interpolation in 3d..I'm answering my own question I think lol. That's very cool.

Comment: @MathBio: Cell arrays are still matrices (like all Matlab matrices, they grow to whatever size you access using a write operation -- if the last iteration through the loop does `IM{4} = ` then you'll have size 4).  The difference is that inside a cell array you can store any Matlab object, including a whole 'nother matrix, and things don't have to be square -- the cell array can happily hold a `1x1` scalar, `2x2` matrix, `10x10` matrix, and `125480x1` vector all next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just thought it was neat that there seemingly was no loop, but 4 arrays were being created. Never encountered cell arrays before, they seem like a very useful construct.

Comment: @MathBio: I mean for him to put this command inside his for loop, replacing the one he already tried.

Comment: Wow I'm dumb. I didn't notice the relevant part was enveloped in a for loop. A little less magical, but I still learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

By using `IM(l)` you're trying to add an entire column vector (`newImage(:)`) to a single element (the l-th element) in the array `IM`, that's why Matlab throws the error.
You should consider concatenation: since `newImage(:)` is a column-vector, replace

```
IM= newImage(:);
```

with

```
IM=[IM newImage(:)];
```

but at the top of the script you should also initialize `IM` as

```
IM=[];
```

At the end of the loop, the resulting `IM` will have `Amount_measurements` columns where 1 column = 1 newImage(:).

*Note #1*: this will only work if `newImage(:)` always has the same length.
*Note #2*: if you know a priori how long the vector `newImage(:)` is and, again, by assuming that its length never changes, you should consider preallocating the `IM` matrix by replacing `IM=[];` with `IM=zeros(X,Amount_measurements);` where `X` is the number of elements in `newImage(:)`. Finally, regarding the concatenation stage, you should replace `IM=[IM newImage(:)];` with `IM(:,l)=newImage(:)`.
*Note #3*: as instead, if the size of `newImage(:)` can change you cannot rely on preallocation and matrices, but you must use cell arrays: the last instruction in your loop should be `IM{l}=newImage(:);`.