# Error " ??? In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

I am trying to execute this code

```
clc;clear;
disp('nombre_de_travée');
NT=input('NT=');  %nombre_de_travé
thetad=0;
thetag=0;
for i=1:NT
    disp('longueur_de_travée');
    l(i)=input(['l(' num2str(i) '):']);
    disp('nombre_de_charge');
    nch=input(['nch(' num2str(i) '):']); %nombre_de_charge
    for j=1:nch
        disp('type_de_charge');
        nc(i,j)=input(['nc(' num2str(i) ',' num2str(j) ')1_2:']); %type_de_charge
        if nc(i,j)==1
            disp('charge concentrée')

            a(i,j)=input(['a(' num2str(i) ',' num2str(j) '):']);
            p(i,j)=input(['p(' num2str(i) ',' num2str(j) '):']);

            thetad(i)=-p(i,j).*a(i,j).*l(i)./6+thetad;
            thetag(i)=p(i,j).*a(i,j).*l(i)./3+thetag;
        elseif nc(i,j)==2
            disp('moment concentrée')
            m(i,j)=input(['m(' num2str(i) ',' num2str(j) '):']);

            thetad(i)=-m(i,j).*l(i)./6+thetad;
            thetag(i)=m(i,j).*l(i)./3+thetag;
        end
    end
end
```

but an error message appears:

```
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements
in B and
 I must be the same.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the *entire* error message.

Comment: (Please note that I went through about half a dozen questions with the EXACT same title to find the one where the same solution applies)

Comment: Here's another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35382118/103167